# Вывести первую статью в отдельном блоке

Tags: php, mysql

Здравствуйте. В базе хранятся записи статей. Я хочу их все вывести на страницу, и это можно реализовать таким кодом:

```
$article_all = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `article` ORDER BY `id` $sort_article LIMIT $otkuda, $set_coll_page");
            while ($item = mysql_fetch_assoc($article_all)) {

 ///тут разметка статьи

}
```

так вот, разметка статьи идет просто выделение ее блоками:

```
<div classs="item">
    статья
</div>
```

Вопрос, как для первой статьи (у которой самый большой id), сделать другую разметку? то есть выделить ее другими блоками.

Буду очень благодарен за помощь и любую полезную информацию.

Comment: банально счетчик и условие `if` ... если счетчик еще нулевой - выводить такой-то блок, иначе - другой

Comment: @АлексейШиманский а что им считать то?

Comment: количество итераций внутри `while` ..если первая итерация то делать одно, и если нет - другое

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$article_all = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `article` ORDER BY `id` $sort_article LIMIT $otkuda, $set_coll_page");
if ($item = mysql_fetch_assoc($article_all)) {
    // разметка для первой статьи
    while ($item = mysql_fetch_assoc($article_all)) {
        // разметка 2-й и последующих статей
    }
}
```

---

PS: функции `mysql_*` являются устаревшими - не следует их использовать для написания нового кода

Comment: Почему комментарий не в ответе?

Comment: Ну так а почему **не в самом ответе** ? В чем прикол писать дополнение в комментарии, которые предназначены .....для комментариев

Answer (score 0):

Самое простое что в голову приходит - ввести флаг:

```
$First=true;
$article_all = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `article` ORDER BY `id` $sort_article LIMIT $otkuda, $set_coll_page");
    while ($item = mysql_fetch_assoc($article_all)) {

    if ($First)
     /// альтернативная разметка первой статьи
    else
     /// разметка 2-й и последующих статей
    $First=false;
}
```